# grouping by three columns and create table (best awk)

Tags: python, awk, count, grouping

I need help with grouping and counting from many columns.

INPUT: tsv file.

Sorted by 1,2 and 4th column.

Header: string, start, stop, length, value

```
chr1    56971   57065   94      0.287234
chr1    565460  565601  141     0.411348
chr1    754342  754488  146     0.520548
chr1    783856  784002  146     0.315068
chr1    789652  789768  116     0.310345
chr1    790532  790628  96      0.520833
chr2    1744623 1744774 151     0.509934
chr2    1744623 1744774 151     0.509934
chr2    1744623 1744774 151     0.509934
chr2    1748501 1748635 134     0.440299
chr2    1748501 1748636 135     0.444444
```

OUTPUT:

```
                    0-10 length ... 90-100 ............140-150... 190-200
chr1:0-60000         A1(0), B1(0)..A2(1),B2(0.287234)..   A,B ... An,Bn
chr1:60000-120000          .             .                 .         . 
.                          .             .                 .         .
.                          .             .                 .         .
chr1:780000-840000       0,0     ..... 1,0.520833 ......1,0.315068..A,B
chr2:0-60000            A1,B1    .....   .        ......   .      .. .
```

A= number of rows in interval 0-60000 (for 2n to 3rd column from input)

B= sum of 5th column in input divided by A (num of rows)

At first group by 1st column and create regions by

```
for i in {0..249480000..60000}
```

and for this region count number of row grouped by length (0..200..10)

I tried:

```
for z in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 X Y
do
for i in {0..249480000..60000}
    do
u=$i
let "u +=60000"
```

"and now I do not know what's next".

I know grouping by one column:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{arr[$1]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}'
```

but this is really hard for me. Please could you help me?

Comment: Please, [edit] so that you show the exact output that is required for the given input. This way things will get more clear.

Comment: Is it better? Sorry for that..

Comment: What happens to ranges that cross your interval boundaries?

Comment: There is two intervals..on axis Y there is $1 and $2 and $3 from input (interval from 0 by 60000 to 249480000 ) and on axis X there is interval for length $4 from input (0 by 10 to 200). In this interval I need count of rows which are located in these intervals and sum of value divided by rows which are located there

Comment: And if it cross, smaller interval has preference or could be counted in both intervals.

Comment: which system are you using (linux, aix, mac, cygwin, ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk -v Separator=' | ' '
    BEGIN{ LenStepSize = 10 ;  IntStepSize = 60000 }
    {
    # Store the labels
    Labels[ $1]++

    # Adapt the Step array size
    if ( IntLastIndex * IntStepSize < $3) IntLastIndex = int( $3 / IntStepSize) + 1
    IntIdx = int( $3 / IntStepSize)

    # Adapt the Length array size
    if( LenLastIndex * LenStepSize < $4) LenLastIndex = int( $4 / LenStepSize) + 1
    LenIdx = int( $4 / LenStepSize)

    # Create the mono "multi" index reference
    Idx = $1 "-" IntIdx "-" LenIdx

    # store the data element
    As[ Idx]++
    Bs[ Idx] += $5
    #printf( "DEBUG: As[%s]: %s | Bs[%s]:%s (+%s)\n", Idx, As[ Idx], Idx, Bs[ Idx], $5)
    }

    END {
       # Print the header
       printf( "Object               ")
       for ( Leng = 0; Leng <= LenLastIndex; Leng++ ) printf( "%s%3d - %3d", Separator, Leng, (Leng + 1) * LenStepSize)
       printf( "\n                     ")
       for ( Leng = 0; Leng <= LenLastIndex; Leng++ ) printf( "%s  length ", Separator)

       # print each element (empty or with value)
       # - lines per label
       for ( Label in Labels) {
          # - per sub section of intervale
          for ( Inter = 0; Inter <= IntLastIndex; Inter++ ) {
             printf( "\n%5s %7d-%7d", Label, Inter * IntStepSize, (Inter + 1) * IntStepSize - 1)

             # column per length section
             for ( Leng = 0; Leng <= LenLastIndex; Leng++ ) {
                Idx = Label "-" Inter "-" Leng
                printf( "%s%d , " ( Bs[ Idx] > 0 ? "%2.3f" : "%-5d") , Separator, As[ Idx], Bs[ Idx] / (As[ Idx] > 0 ? As[ Idx] : 1))
                }
             }
             print ""
          }
       }
    ' tsv.file
```

- Using an simili multidimensionnal array (1 index but composed with 3 
  element)
- dynamic based on element size (avoid to create a huge nearly empty array in memory)
- doesn't suite for huge data file (due to memory impact)
- output format is basic (no column or row sizing based on content, ...)

  - added the `Separator` variable at the start of awk to see (in this case) column but let you set any pattern as separator (like space or ",", ...) to suite your real need

Comment: I tried it, for count of rows works well, but value B doesn't work :-( But it is really great job, I am amazed..

Comment: I tried to find, where could be a problem in your script, but I didn't :-( Still time I have problem with counting value ("B") :-( I think, it is showing only integers but I need float (f.e. : 0.45)

Comment: added some comment for a better understanding and output of B's were `%d`, so no decimal  number, I change it by '%2.3f' and adpat some other formating output

Comment: Thanks for the comments, that is better for me to understand of script. It is worikng and it is reallly great job... Thanks a lot